# Select necesary columns in a table in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two models: Room and User

Room :

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

User:

```
public class User
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the list of room names, that a special user, here user1, is belong to.

Here is my code:

```
  List<string> MyRoomsNames = _context.Rooms
               .Include(p => p.Users)
               .Select(r => new { r.Name,r.Users})
               .Where(r => r.Users.Contains(user1)).ToList();
```

And, here is the error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Name,
> System.Collections.Generic.List<Core.Models.User> Users>>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: You are selecting an anonymous type which cannot be converted to a list of string.
If you change the select to `.Select(r=>r.Name)` it should work

Comment: @PaulKaram You are right. It works. I thought `Users` must be included in `Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with structure you had was doing the `Where` after the `Select`. For instance given the following:

```
List<string> MyRoomsNames = _context.Rooms
    .Select(r => r.Name)
    .Where(r => r.Users.Contains(user1))
    .ToList();
```

This won't work because the `Where` clause will operate on the results of the `Select` so to query users you'd want to have selected them, but then this will conflict with the desired return type.  Switching the order of operations:

```
List<string> MyRoomsNames = _context.Rooms
    .Where(r => r.Users.Contains(user1))
    .Select(r => r.Name)
    .ToList();
```

This will give you the desired output as the `Where` clause will be applied against the Room entities and their related Users.

One further improvement for the query would be to do the check against the user ID rather than comparing entity references. EF *may* optimize that "Users.Contains", or it may be doing something unsavory like client-side evaluation, but an alternative that would just do an Index check in the DB:

```
var userId = user1.Id; 
List<string> MyRoomsNames = _context.Rooms
    .Where(r => r.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == userId))
    .Select(r => r.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Or since you have Rooms associated to the User entity, check how "user1" was loaded and whether Rooms was Included:

```
List<string> MyRoomsNames = user1.Rooms
    .Select(r => r.Name)
    .ToList();
```

This could trigger a lazy load or a `NullReferenceException` if the user's rooms were not eager loaded (`Include`). Alternatively the rooms could be queried through the user:

```
var userId = user1.Id; 
List<string> MyRoomsNames = _context.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Rooms.Select(r => r.Name))
    .ToList();
```